# Why am I suddenly "python.dll is not installed" error?

Tags: python, installation

On Windows, suddenly my python instead of showing version 3.7.9 was running a higher version than installed. So I uninstalled and attempting to reinstall failed due to "python.dll is not installed error.

I was able to install a 32 bit version of python, but installing the 64 bit is  resulting in this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed mysys2 and added it to the path which also has its own Python. This caused some conflicts while installing python. After removing mysys2 from the system PATH, the issue resolved.